# Chrome extension that hides other extensions icons

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, bookmarklet

I was trying to create a **Chrome** extension that hides all the existing extension icons (can't be disabled), is there any way to do it?

Comment: I kind of hope there isn't.

Comment: Any way to take control over url bar ? like resizing url bar width?

Comment: Chrome doesn't expose any programmatic means to manipulate its own UI representation.

Answer (score 1):

Extensions cannot change chrome's settings or appearance(with a few exeptions).
Extension apis like you are suggesting would be very invasive and most likely unwanted from most users.